# Conversion error when calculating VAT C#-

Tags: c#, type-conversion, price

In my app, I wanted to calculate a **price** (net) -> (gross) from the **text box via a button**.
I get the values from the textbox `txtPurchasingPrice`.
But since the value is stored as a string in a database, of course I also get a conversion error.

The conversion is the least of the problems.
How do I get the value that is calculated into the label or textbox? (without saving it to the database). It should only be displayed. If needed when you click on the button.

```cs
private void btnPriceCalculation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(txtPurchasingPrice.Text == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Bitte gib den Einkaufspreis Netto an.");
        return;
    }
    double PurchasingPrice = Convert.ToInt32(txtPurchasingPrice.Text);
    double PurchasingPriceBrut = Convert.ToInt32(PurchasingPrice * 0.19);
    PurchasingPriceBrut = Convert.ToInt32(txtPurchasingPriceBrut.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double PurchasingPrice = Convert.ToInt32(txtPurchasingPrice.Text);
    double PurchasingPriceBrut = Convert.ToInt32(PurchasingPrice * 0.19);
    PurchasingPriceBrut = Convert.ToInt32(txtPurchasingPriceBrut.Text);
```

the last row must edit in
lbPurchasingPriceBrut.Text = PurchasingPriceBrut.ToString();

Sorry